# Cannot connect to Wi-Fi networks after additional SSD install

Tags: networking, ssd, sata, interference

I installed a new SATA III SSD on my new laptop (GIGABYTE A5 K1 with the Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MH network adapter) and now it can't connect to any Wi-Fi network, even though it detects them. After removing the drive, things work again as expected, putting it back lets the issue reoccur.

Is the new SSD causing some kind of interference? And how to fix that?

EDIT: I put another lower capacity drive of the same brand and it worked fine. Probably the drive is causing interference somehow, I will make another edit once done testing.

EDIT 2: I put the suspected drive into the old laptop and no apparent issues, so I'm going to keep this configuration since I've cloned the other drive... For the record if someone comes later with a similar issue, the only difference between the two is the capacity, the one that caused me issues is slightly larger (720 vs 480 GB) (perhaps it drew more power which caused the issue to appear?). Plus I used actual screws to attach the drive into a metal piece (the first time, I didn't have spare ones so used Chatterton tape instead to attach the drive to that metal piece, maybe the lack of screws had something to do with interference? I don't know) which itself (metal piece) was screwed into the laptop to have the drive fixed into place.

Comment: Driver issue (SSD) ?  Connection issue inside (problem with the SSD board)?

Comment: I'm not sure because the SSD seems to work normally. Besides, I have another one like this one except for capacity and it works without causing any issues on my old laptop.

Comment: I am not sure.  See if there us a connection issue (physical connection) or if the problem SSD uses more power on the power buss

Comment: What error do you get, just a message like `Can't connect to this network` or anything else?

Comment: Yeah, it is that error that shows after trying to connect for a few seconds...

Comment: If OS is Windows, what if you try Live Linux? Does it connect when on other OS?

Comment: No, I have not tried that yet. I'm currently cloning the other drive on my old laptop to see if I can use this one on it instead. Since I put that one on my new laptop and it didn't cause that issue. I'm assuming the drive is faulty for now, or since it has higher capacity it could be drawing more power and causing the interference.

Comment: I'm assuming the drive is faulty for now, or since it has higher capacity it could be drawing more power    ----    I think this is your issue.  See if you can be satisfied with the prior SSD.

Comment: +1 for thoughtful troubleshooting and inclusion in question.